# custom conversion program in python?

Tags: python, converters

I would like to do something like as follows:

```
h=@ , e=( , l=& , o=!
```

So, in the above example, when you type `hello`, it gives back `@(&&!`, and vise versa.

(I would perfer it in Python, but it doesn't have to be.)

I would like to make a small utility of this sort. Can anyone help? Thanks!

**EDIT:** "Basically I would like to be able to assign some letters a unique character. Then, when you run the utility, it asks for your input. Then you type what you want in any order. Using the example above: "hello"="@(&&!" , "elloh"="(&&!@" , "looleh"="&!!&(@" and so forth."

Comment: Do you want to use this inside a Python program or as a seaparate tool?

Comment: If you are referring to "h=@ , e=( , l=& , o=!" that was just an example. Basically I would like to be able to assign some letters a unique character. Then, when you run the utility, it asks for your input. Then you type what you want in any order. Using the example above: "hello"="@(&&!" , "elloh"="(&&!@" , "looleh"="&!!&(@" and so forth. Sorry if I didn't explain it well before. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 7):

**In Python2**, you could use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
import string
table = string.maketrans(
    'helo',
    '@(&!',)

In [17]: 'hello'.translate(table)
Out[17]: '@(&&!'

In [18]: 'looleh'.translate(table)
Out[18]: '&!!&(@'
```

Or, you could use `unicode.translate`:

```
In [19]: table = {ord(k):v for k, v in zip(u'helo', u'@(&!')}

In [20]: u'hello'.translate(table)
Out[20]: u'@(&&!'
```

Lutz Horn's answer shows how you could build a single table which can perform both the forward and backward translation.

---

**In Python3**, `string.maketrans` [has been replaced](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html) by `bytes.maketrans`:

```
>>> table = bytes.maketrans(b'helo', b'@(&!')
>>> b'hello'.translate(table)
b'@(&&!'

>>> 'hello'.translate({ord(k):v for k, v in zip('helo', '@(&!')})
'@(&&!'
```

Comment: maketrans is removed from python 3x

Comment: Where is the 'and vise versa' part?

Comment: @LutzHorn: Perhaps the reverse translation has been left as an exercise for the OP...

Comment: I think I didn't explain that well before. I have revised the original post. Also, I have plugged in the code to python and I get various errors, different for each.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Let's just get the first part working before I get another worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing small utility [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr).

In the following example, every uneaven line (1, 3, 5, 7) is input, every even line (2, 4, 6, 8) is output.

```
$ tr 'helo@(&!' '@(&!helo'
hello
@(&&!
@(&&!
hello
stackoverflow
stack!v(rf&!w
stack!v(rf&!w
stackoverflow
```

Comment: I replied to your comment above and revised the original post. I think it will better explain things.